# User with Email not confirmed is still SignedIn

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

Using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Identity Server 4 I am Signing In a user as follows:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, isPersistent: true, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```

The user is successfully signed in even if the email was not verified.

But I have set `SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail` to true ... What am I missing?

On the Auth Identity Server Startup I have the following configuration:

```
  services
    .AddIdentity<User, Role>(x => {
      x.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
      x.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;  
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

  services
    .AddIdentityServer(y => {
      y.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
      y.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
      y.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
      y.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
      y.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/login";
      y.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/logout";
    })
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(getIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(getApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(getClients())
    .AddAspNetIdentity<User>();
```

Comment: Have you generated an Email Confimation Token after register the user? Like this: var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to verify the result of the action and then take action. In account/login, something like this:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, true, true);

if (result.Succeeded)
    ; // OK

if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
    ; // initiate two-factor authentication

// User exists but is not allowed because e.g. email is not verified.
if (result.IsNotAllowed)
{
    var isLockedOut = await _userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user);
    if (isLockedOut)
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout), new { model.ReturnUrl });

        await _userManager.AccessFailedAsync(failedUser);
    }
}

// something went wrong, show form with error
return View(model);
```

Comment: +1 for your comment there, "User exists but is not allowed because e.g. email is not verified." "IsNotAllowed" is not very clear wording